# Absolute & relative content is displayed differently

Tags: css, position

My question is:
If I'm in a situation where `relative` and `absolute` positioning should have the same result (for example, if I apply this position on a `div` element which is the only element in the page), and that I set a specific width to my element, why is the `div` content displayed differently, and is there a way to fix this.

A simple example should help to understand:

**Using `position: relative;`:**

```css
.test-border {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 3px solid #DFDFDF;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-border">
  <ul>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Using `position: absolute;`:**

```css
.test-border {
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 3px solid #DFDFDF;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-border">
  <ul>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you look this page in a browser, and replace absolute by relative, you will see that the list is not positioned the same way when it's container is `absolute`/`relative`. This is true on Firefox and Chrome.

For me, definitions of `relative`/`absolute` values doesn't explain this behavior, so if someone can explain it, it will help me ;-) ...
And important also, any workaround to get the same result for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because elements positioned absolutely do not collapse margins while those positioned relatively do. `ul` elements often have `margin` and `padding` applied automatically by the browser. When positioned relatively this `margin` is collapsed into the `body` `margin` which is why there appears to be less "padding" above and below the list.

**From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position:**

> Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow. This means they have no impact on the layout of later siblings. Also, though absolutely positioned boxes have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

To stop this from happening add `margin: 0;` to the `ul`:

```css
.test-border {
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 3px solid #DFDFDF;
}
.test-border ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-border">
  <ul>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand, because the modification has to be done on elements positioned in "static" (ul). Does it means that if I want to have the same result between relative and absolute, I have to remove margins of all children elements (in my example, there is only <ul>, but in fact I have more things) ?

Comment: @user1961659 It depends on a number of factors so it is very difficult for me to say what would be effected. If you have multiple `ul` on top of each other, all `static` with top and bottom `margin` then yes, the margins will collapse into each other. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing may provide a bit more insight into collapsing margins.

Answer (score 0):

An element that is placed relative, has still relation to it's parent. Making it inherit some of it's styles.

An element that is placed absolute, lies above the document flow. It has no relation to it's 'parent'.

When you disable the `margin` and `padding` of the body and HTML tag, you'll see that the difference is gone: http://jsfiddle.net/oc0n3vmL/